# Strange Javascript behaviour

Tags: javascript

I am using JQuery to append images, like this:

```
$('#event_list_main').append('<img class="listed_event" id="event_'+event_counter+'" data-count="'+event_counter+'" src="final_tutorial_buttons/event.png" height="50" width="50" onclick="highlight();" />');
```

I am assign a `highlight` function to each image I create and append! The problem is that the highlight function does not execute.

```
//Highlight function
function highlight()
{
    var indicator = $(this).data("count");
    alert(indicator);

}
```

the "this" part doesnt seem to work.I want this to refer to each event created.

for example if I created 3 events

event_1
event_2
event_3

and I click on "image event_2" then "this" must refer to "image-event_2"

Comment: Can you confirm that `highlight` is a global function?

Comment: Also, consider delegating the "click" event to the `'#event_list_main'` element...

Answer (score 4):

Try `onclick="highlight.call(this);"`

However, it would be **much** cleaner to properly attach an event handler:

```
var img = $('<img class="listed_event" id="event_'+event_counter+'" data-count="'+event_counter+'" src="final_tutorial_buttons/event.png" height="50" width="50" />');
img.on('click', highlight);
$('#event_list_main').append(img);
```

Or even more readable:

```
var img = $('<img/>', {
    'class': 'listed_event',
    id: 'event_' + event_counter,
    src: 'final_tutorial_buttons/event.png'
}).height(50).width(50).data('count', event_counter).on('click', highlight);
$('#event_list_main').append(img);
```

Comment: It would be even cleaner this way: `var img = $('<img />').attr({class: 'listed_event', id: 'event_' + event_counter, 'data-count': event_counter, src: 'final_tutorial_buttons/event.png'}).click(highlight).appendTo('#event_list_main')`. On several lines, of course.

Comment: It would be even more cleaner with a template.

Answer (score 1):

That's not unexpected behavior, you're not passing the `this` value. But you expect it because jQuery does that automatically for you.

This is an easy fix:

```
$('#event_list_main').append('<img class="listed_event" id="event_'+event_counter+'" data-count="'+event_counter+'" src="final_tutorial_buttons/event.png" height="50" width="50" onclick="highlight.call(this);" />');
```

Even though it'd be better to replace it all together with:

```
$('<img class="listed_event" id="event_' +
     event_counter + '" data-count="' +
     event_counter + '" src="final_tutorial_buttons/event.png" height="50" width="50" />')
     .click(highlight).appendTo("#event_list_main");
```

Please see [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) post for more information about how `call()`, `apply()` and `this`.